# How to allow anonymous user create comments (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, blogs

I want to allow anonymous users create comments to posts. After any anon user create a comment I want to show "Anonymous" above his comment. I already did that when a registered user leaves a comment on, his name will be displayed next to his commentary but how can I achieve this?

Authentication system in blog is Devise.

comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.save
redirect_to @post
end

def destroy
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy
redirect_to @comment.post
 end
end
```

piece of code that render comment form from show.html.erb:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<p><%= comment.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %>
by <%=comment.user.fullname%></p>
<p><%= comment.text %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete comment", [@post, comment], 
:method => :delete, :confirm =>  "Are  you sure?"%></p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
<p><%= f.text_area :text %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Post comment" %></p>
<% end
```

Comment: Are these anonymous users registered users? Meaning, do they have user records created by Devise, and they can leave comments as anonymous? Or do you want to allow non-registered users to also leave comments as anonymous?

Comment: No, anonymous users are not registered. I want that non-registered users, who don't have users records by devise, can leave comments to posts and above theirs comments always be "by Anonymous"

Comment: Seems like you'll just need to add logic in your controller and/or view to check if `current_user.id` exists or not, and then just display "Anonymous" accordingly. Your `Comment` model will have to make sure that the foreign key to `user_id` allows null values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but you can use if and ||.

In your controller change:

```
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

to

```
@comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user || nil
```

And in your view change:

```
by <%=comment.user.fullname%></p>
```

to

```
by <%= (comment.user.fullname if comment.user) || "Anonymous" %></p>
```

Comment: I added that to controller and to view file but after I wrote comment(as Anonymous) and pressed 'post comment' nothing happened. I mean list of comments is still empty